# Sound problems with Jabra Evolve2 65 and GNOME in openSUSE Leap 15.3

Tags: bluetooth, opensuse, wireless-headset

Did anybody succeed to make the Jabra Evolve2 65 headset work in openSUSE 15.3 running GNOME?

- A2DP Sink works fine in stereo
- HFP and HSP (mono) cannot play the test sounds; I only hear some noise
- most importantly, the microphone does not work (no input signal)

What could I do to debug?

Versions of significant packages are:

- `kernel-default-5.3.18-150300.59.68.1.x86_64`
- `pulseaudio-14.2-4.2.x86_64`
- `bluez-5.55-3.8.1.x86_64`

Comment: Did you fix your issue? I'm facing the same issue here

Comment: @CelsoMarques Then upvote the question. Answers will be found as answers. Trust me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer I was looking for, but a work-around at least:

If you use the USB device (Jabra Link 380) that comes with the headset, you realize that the device is not a Bluetooth adapter, but a combined audio and keyboard device.
Thus the system sees an audio device with stereo speakers and a mono microphone.
In addition you get some buttons to control multimedia.

I tested it, and I could record and play back sounds correctly.

(Unrelated, but maybe interesting: I tried the Ubuntu Studio 22.04 live media, and there the headset worked in HFP mode (in addition to stereo playback in A2DP mode) using the built-in Bluetooth adapter)